# Clone brush is cloning from material colour, not texture?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I've pressed ctrl+lmb to pick the part of my texture I want to clone from, but it isn't cloning the texture, it's cloning my material diffuse colour. (I've purposely turned my diffuse colour red to be sure). Anybody know how to get it to clone from my texture? I'm in multi texture at mo but it doesn't work in glsl either. Thanks.

[image]

images of my texture tab, and the results of the clone brush in both glsl and multi texture mode. If you need to see any particular tabs within the texture tab let me know. Thank you.

[image: glsl with tex tab open]

[image: multi texture with tex tab open]

Comment: Can you upload a Texture tab in the Properties Panel, the one after Materials tab

Comment: Thanks for looking @IgorTatarnikov. I think I've done what you asked.

Comment: I know some great tutorials  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yDGZZYRsyCk.             https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=uxD0qaTFZnk

Comment: I've not been able to figure out what's happened here, but I've managed to get the clone brush working by appending my model into a brand new file with factory settings. The clone brush is now acting like a clone brush!